# Using multiple GPU libraries at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to use two libraries in python that use the GPU. `PyOpenCL` for renering and `Open3D` for visualization.

However when I import both libraries at the same time, the interpreter crashes:

```py
import open3d
import pyopencl
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It does not matter in which order I import the libraries.

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 520
Driver: beignet-opencl-icd 1.1.1-2
Python: 3.5.2
Open3d: 0.7.0.0
PyOpenCL: 2019.1.1
```

### Question

Is there a solution for using those two libraries in one interpreter?